Construction of a graph on even number of vertices with required eccentricities.
I was trying to construct a graph on an even number of vertices $n$ such that center and periphery contain an equal number of vertices, i.e. $|C(G)|=|P(G)| =\frac{n}{2}$. Till now, I was able to draw two such graphs. One is path graph $P_4$ and another two graphs as follows


My doubt: Are there any other graph (s) with different radius and diameter? Is there any generalized construction for the same?

A clique with one pendant edge for each vertex seems a natural generalization. Also "center and periphery contain an equal number of vertices" is not equivalent to "$|C(G)|=|P(G)| =\frac{n}{2}$", since you can have vertices that are neither in $C(G)$ nor in $P(G)$. A more general class of such graphs: replace in my construction the complete graph with any graph of constant radius.

@caduk that's a great point which I missed. Thanks. I will edit my question.

@caduk if center and periphery both contain n/2 vertices then there are no other vertices left? Am I right?

We can have center and periphery with the same number of vertices, but lower than $n/2$

yeah that is possible. That is why I have put a condition half vertices in centre and the rest of the half in the periphery.,

If you take a cycle graph with pendant edges for each vertex, then you have a graph with arbitrary big radius. The diameter will always be one more than the radius since peripheral vertices needs to be adjacent to some center vertices.

@caduk Thanks a lot

Why the bounty? What is missing in my answer?

@caduk Nothing is wrong in your answer sir/ma'am. I just wanted to draw more attention to know if there are other possibilities.

@caduk why did you remove the answer? it could benefit other readers even if not the OP

@KennethKho my answer is in the comments above, I'm not sure it deserves a longer answer.

One other possible generalization would be the following:
Take a graph $G$ on n-vertices and some integer $r\ge 2$. Now consider $K_{nr}$ and partition $V(K_{nr})$ into $r$ sets $A_1,\ldots, A_r$ all of size $n$. Also take $r$ copies $G_1, \ldots, G_r$ of $G$. Now for all $i\in [r]$ we add edges between all $v\in A_i$ and $w\in G_i$. The diameter of this constructed graph is $3$; all vertices in $V(K_{nr})$ have eccentricity $2$ and all vertices in $G_1,\ldots, G_r$ have eccentricity $3$. Your second example is a special case of this construction, if we pick $G = K_2$ and $r = 2$. It does not cover other cases though, like the example of taking a cycle and adding a pendant vertex to each vertex of the cycle.
